# How to do a "transition.to" to a value

Tags: coronasdk

So here is my problem,

I want to use the easing algorithm of the transition.to function to have a smooth transition of my physics Time Step when the game is lost.

So far I've just set the value to 1/300:

```
physics.setTimeStep(1/300)
```

It's been 2 days of useless searching efforts..

I tried a lot of things but anything relevant.. 
I simply do not know whether or not it is possible..

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! what have you tried so far? what issues you faced?

Answer (score 0):

Well after three days of searching finally found that on GitHub :

[Robert Penner's Easing Library Lua Port](https://github.com/EmmanuelOga/easing)

Hoping it will help someone else ! ;)